# Splitting ratio of beam splitter in opposite direction

Tags: optics

Is it possible with applying certain type of coating such that a beam splitter can have different splitting ratio when light ray go through it from opposite side? For example, 50/50 in one way and 100% transmittance in the other. Thank you.